# How to check for substrings

Tags: string, lua, substring

```
a="hello"
b="hi"

io.write("enter a or b or both:")
c=io.read()

if c=="hello" then    
    print(b)    
elseif c=="hi" then    
    print (a)    
elseif c~=a or b then    
    print ("unknown word")    
end
```

The problem is when I write both : `hello hi`, it is showing :`unknown word`.

How can I fix this?
I also tried with table something like `d={},d.a="hello",d.b="hi"` but the same problem.

Comment: The last condition is superfluous. You just want an `else` there. No harm done, as the condition is always true.

Comment: Well, if you want to handle that case too, add a condition for someone entering both. (in any order? / multiple times?)

Comment: i just put it so i can see from the console if it can read both strings but thnx for mentioning.

Comment: yes but what about more words?

Comment: Just a tip: Print out what you read in, so you learn what `io.read()` really read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare *words* instead of *substrings*, try this:

```
function normalize(x)
    return " "..x.." "
end

mywords=normalize("hello hi")

function ok(x)
    return mywords:match(normalize(x))~=nil

end

print(ok("hello"))
print(ok("hi"))
print(ok("high"))
```

Answer (score 3):

`==` is used to test equality. But the string `"hello hi"` is neither equal to `"hello"` nor `"hi"`. To test if it contains a substring, use pattern matching:

```
local found = false
if c:match("hello") then    
    print(a)  
    found = true
end 
if c:match("hi") then    
    print(b) 
    found = true
end 
if not found then
    print ("unknown word")    
end
```

Comment: thank you very much it worked and sorry but i can not upvote yet.

Comment: This will mistake `high` for `hi`, for instance.

Comment: Right, whether it's correct depends on what **substring** means, it's not clear from the question.